# Creating a database model with categories and multiple features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design, relational-database

I am building a rails site which rates places.

Each place belongs to a category. Each category has many features. Thus a place can belong to only one category but can have many of it's features selected. If a place belongs to category 1, then it can have only the (1 or many)features of category 1 and not anything else.
Also each place age groups.

What would be the rails way to accomplish this?

- Should I have separate table for age groups or have them part of the
  places table itself?
- How do I associate the features to places?
  Should I have a separate table as shown below(PlacesFeatures table)?

I am using SQLite for dev & would be using postgres(on Heroku) for production.

---

This is the table structure I have thought of(table & it's columns):

**Place table:**

```
INTEGER id 
STRING name
INTEGER category_id
STRING address
FLOAT rating
```

**Category Table:**

```
INTEGER id
STRING name
```

**Features Table:**(The form would show features per category to be selected by querying this table)

```
INTEGER id
STRING name
INTEGER category_id
```

**AgeGroup Table:**(A Place can have multiple age groups selected)

```
INTEGER id
INTEGER place_id
BOOLEAN zero_to_three
BOOLEAN four_to_eight
BOOLEAN nine_to_twelve
BOOLEAN thirteen_above
```

**PlacesFeatures Table:**

```
INTEGER id
INTEGER place_id
INTEGER category_id
BOOLEAN feature_1
BOOLEAN feature_2
...
BOOLEAN feature_n
```

Relationships:

```
Place 
   belongs_to :category
   has_many   :age_groups

Category 
   has_many :places
   has_many :features

AgeGroup
   belongs_to :place
```

A Place entry would be creating through a form submission.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either have boolean flags for age groups in Places table or separate PlacesAgeGroups table like this:

**PlacesAgeGroups Table:**

```
INTEGER id
INTEGER place_id
INTEGER age_group_id
```

**AgeGroups Table:**

```
INTEGER id
INTEGER description
```

Similarly, PlacesFeatues should rather have references to featues, one feature per record.

**PlacesFeatures Table:**

```
INTEGER id
INTEGER place_id
INTEGER category_id # (this is optional, as it's already set in Places table)
INTEGER feature_id
```

Comment: Thanks! This sounds like a good way to do it. I'll have a separate table for ages. I will try implementing this and see if I face any difficulties.